# How to block Cassandra from trying to connect automatically

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I have this project where I'm trying to connect to different DB types based on configuration. 
I have it working for Mongo and MySQL and switch by loading Beans by using `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "settings.data.source", havingValue = "mongodb")`

Now I want to add Cassandra, but once I added the following dependency to my pom, it starts trying to connect to Cassandra nodes on localhost.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I want to have more control over when the Cassandra resources are loaded.

It doesn't try to connect automatically when I added Mongo dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Anyone familiar with this behavior? How can I control this? I don't always need a Cassandra connection...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may disable Cassandra auto configuration,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Use this for higher spring boot version:
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class, CassandraAutoConfiguration.class})`

Comment: thank you , that saved me a lot of time to fix unit tests

Answer (score 0):

Yep, That's it, thanks!

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={
        CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class, 
        MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class, 
        MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
```

For both my `@SpringBootApplication` and `@Configuration` classes.